# AJAX-Request from Phonegap Apps

Tags: ajax, dns, cordova, extjs

I'm working on a mobile web-app using HTML5 and sencha touch. My next step is to add some native capability using phonegap. My app uses Ajax requests to retrieve data from a server component and i am not sure if ajax will work within phonegap packed apps? Should i use JSONP instead?

Answer (score 1):

No need for JSONP. Since the html files are local files, there is no cross domain restriction.

Comment: That sonly true if all files and data sources are on the device. I believe they are talking about server side data.

Comment: @michael No, read the question again - meq is talking specifically if "ajax will work within phonegap packed apps". I've used PhoneGap (and implemented some code), so yes, my answer is correct - no cross domain restriction, and ajax will work on all domains meq needs to connect to.

Comment: I read it again and it still says "uses Ajax requests to retrieve data from a server component". That implies, to me at least, an external data source. If it means a 'server' component packed within the phoneGap app then that is not clearly stated.

Comment: It's pretty clear that OP is talking about making an HTTP request here.